# Get one file from git using chef

Tags: git, chef-infra

There is one config file in my git repo that I want to use in a chef recipe. What would be the best way of getting that file, in the recipe?

The git cookbook only allows checking out the entire repo, from what I can see at least (https://docs.getchef.com/resource_git.html). I really want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Git web frontend (gitweb, Github, Gitlab, Gitblit) allows you to download raw files from the repository via HTTP, then the easiest solution would be to pick that up in Chef using `remote_file`. All of the mentioned Git web frontends allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific than the other answer, you would use it like:

```
execute "git archive --remote=#{repo_url} HEAD:#{File.dirname(from_path)} #{File.basename(from_path)} | tar -x" do
  creates to_path
  cwd ::File.dirname(to_path)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git archive` together with `tar` like:

```
git archive --remote=<repo_url> HEAD:<path/to/directory> filename | tar -x
```